# Increase Counter While doinbackground is running async task

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I am running an async task. 
In the doinbackground method i have a method that returns int or some other value may be boolean value some times.

I also want to increase my progress bar as it goes to finishing.
problem is how to keep the track of counter ?
Some times db query may take some time and some times it goes faster . :)

```
   public void getAllSchoolsSearchResult(InputBean nb ,  SearchLogic mLogic){

    mSRLogic=mLogic;
    new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, List<SResultModel>>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            mProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
            mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<SResultModel> doInBackground(
                Void... paramArrayOfParams) {

            progressbar_Status=0;
            while(progressbar_Status<100){

                progressbar_Status += 1;

                publishProgress(progressbar_Status);

            }
            if(ConnectionProvider.checkConnection()==false){
                return null;
            }
            return SearchResultHandler.searchStudent(searchAllSchools);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<SResultModel> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(mProgressDialog!=null&&mProgressDialog.isShowing()){
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            mProgressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);

        }






    }.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

publishProgress can't be used like this.

From your code, you are showing the progress bar (while doing nothing) and then when it reaches 100% then you request the students.

The publishProgress should be inside the

```
SearchResultHandler.searchStudent()
```

depending on how it's implemented. If it doesn't have a loop inside, you won't be able to publish any progress.

In this cases, use an INDETERMINATE progress dialog, and do nothing in your doInBackground

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    mProgressDialog.show();
}   


protected List<SResultModel> doInBackground(Void... paramArrayOfParams) {
    if(!ConnectionProvider.checkConnection()) return null;
    return SearchResultHandler.searchStudent(searchAllSchools);
}
```

Comment: No, there is no progress in the indeterminate dialog, just a wait dialog because the time estimation is unknown.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of an unknown duration you should probably be using an indeterminate progress bar which you can set via the `android:indeterminate` layout property or `setIndeterminate` method.

If you know how many operations you're doing you can hold a member variable inside the asynctask or a local variable in the `doInBackground` method.

Comment: Hi i used this worked , But the 0% is not increasing with respect to progress update